# Trouble toggling the userInteractionEnabled property in iOS

Tags: ios, event-handling

I am developing a tic tac toe game for iOS and I am using a combination of UIButtons and UIImageViews to allow for user interaction and to display the moves made.  My problem is that the buttons continue to accept user input before the cpu makes it's move, which breaks my game logic.  I have made several attempts to toggle the userInteractionEnabled property, but I have only been able to turn it off.  The engine that gets everything started in the game is my buttonPressed method.  I also toggle the userInteractionEnabled property within this method and therein lies my problem: **How do I re-enable the property after disabling user interaction? Is there a method that is called in between events that I can overwrite?**

I have searched the web and I have searched through the developer documentation provided by Apple and I found information on the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods.  However, from what I understand, those methods need to be explicitly called which brings me back to my original problem of not being able to call those functions without the user's interaction.

If anyone can help, I would greatly appreciate it!  I have been racking my brain over this for the past couple of weeks and I am just not seeing a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that for a game like tic-tac-toe, calculating the countermove should be so fast that it can be done immediately in response to the first button press. If you're doing something complicated to calculate the next move, like kicking off a thread, you might want to reconsider that.

Let's say, though, that your game is something like chess or go, where coming up with a countermove might take a bit longer. Your view controller should have a method to make a move for the current player, let's call it -makeMove:. Your -buttonPressed action should call that method to make a move for the user. In response, -makeMove: should update the state of the game, switch the current player to the next player. If the new current player is the computer, it should then disable the controls and start the process of calculating the next move. Let's imagine that's done by invoking some NSOperation, so that coming up with the next move is an asynchronous task. Once the operation has come up with a move, it should again invoke -makeMove: (by calling -performSelectorOnMainThread:), which will again update the game state and the current player. This time, though, it should see that the new current player is not the computer, and so it should re-enable the controls.

Comment: Caleb, thank you for your suggestion.  I think I should explain my setup a bit more.  I call performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: to delay drawing the computer's move.  The problem is that the flag I use to determine whether it is the computer's turn or the player's turn gets flipped after the computer calculates it's move. So I have a similar setup to your suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work.  I tried changing the flag after the performSelector call, but the user is still able to tap and update the board before the computer's move is drawn.  Would performSelector work to toggle input?